# how to overlay the cernatin point value in levelplot using R?

Tags: r, raster, levelplot

I have the raster (DEM)

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 164, 96, 15744  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 83.47915, 83.50582, 28.80114, 28.84669  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : -4.737531, 0.554273  (min, max)
```

and I want to overlay the point values

```
p = -3.9837500 -2.6327150 -1.4857878 -1.0200000 -0.7716000
```

in the following lat-long

```
lat=28.80046, 28.80381, 28.81314, 28.81314, 28.81144
lon=83.49621, 83.49524, 83.49450, 83.49450, 83.49201
```

Comment: What kind of searching have you done? Surely there are examples of plotting points on whatever graphical output you current packages are producing. Y.

Comment: I did plot using 'plot' command and it works. But I need to plot using 'levelplot', rasterVis package.

Answer (score 0):

Make a spatialpointsdataframe;

```
p = -3.9837500 -2.6327150 -1.4857878 -1.0200000 -0.7716000
lat=28.80046, 28.80381, 28.81314, 28.81314, 28.81144
lon=83.49621, 83.49524, 83.49450, 83.49450, 83.49201

df <- data.frame(lat = lat, lon= lon, z = p)
coordinates(df) <- ~lon+lat
crs(df) <- projection(yourRas)
```

And add to rasterVis plot with 'sp.points'

```
levelplot(yourRas) +
    layer(sp.points(df, size=3))
```